# How do I find the function of parabola with only 1 point, that’s also x intercept?

Tags: functions

So I’ve been given a task to find:
a) linear function given the points: $[-2;-3];[2;9],$ easy, it   should be $3x+3=y$
b) It’s $x$-intercept, that should be $[-1;0]$
Now to the tricky part
c) I have to find a parabola $(f(x)=x^2+bx+c)$ that touches the   linear function only in this point (the linear function doesn’t   go through the parabola, they only touch in $[-1;0]$)
Then I have to find the $x$-intercepts for the parabola I’ve found (I assume $[-1;0]$ is one of them)
Graph
Teacher gave me a hint, of using the derivative of parabola, that’s $2x+b$
The thing is I have no clue what to do.
I tried to get the angle of linear function growth of $X$ / growth of $y$, $4/12= 3$
Meaning $f’(x)$ of parabola should also be $3$.
So $3=2x+b$
Then I had no idea what to do, so I just put the $x$ of the $x$-intercept, meaning I got $3=-2+b,\; b=5$
Then I put the $b=5$ into the parabola, again assuming $X = -1$;
$0=(-1)^2+5(-1)+c$
So $0= 1-5+4$
$\quad C=4$
And I got $y=x^2+5x+4$
This is the result I came up with, but it seems I assumed $x=-1$ way too much. If anyone knows how to do this properly please help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can find two categories of parabolas that satisfy your wanted features. one is upward (i.e. the coefficient of $x^2$ is positive) which is on the left side of your linear function; The other category has a negative coefficient for the $x^2$ and is on the right side of your line. The question only wanted the a=1 answer (if I've understood correctly.) The use of derivative of parabola here is because that the linear function is tangent to the parabola ,meaning that at some given point the slope of the parabola would be equal to the slope of this linear function which is $3$.
For $a=1 \gt 0$ in $f(x)=ax^2 +bx+c$
$$
f'(-1)=2(1)(-1)+b \\
f'(-1)=3 \\
\text{then} \\
-2(1) +b = 3 \\
\text{so}\\
b = 5
$$
We also know that the point $(-1,0)$ is a point of the parabola therefore:
$$ \begin{align}
f(-1)&=(1)(-1)^2 +b(-1)+c=0 \\
&=1+(-5)+c =0 \\
\text{so} \\
c &= 4
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT

At $ (-1,0)$ point
$$y=x^2+bx+c $$
$$ x=-1,y=0\to~1-b+c=0\tag 1$$
slope $y^{'}=2 x+b$
$$x=-1, y^{'}=3$$
$$-2+b=3\tag 2$$

From 1),2) can you next solve for $(a,b)?$